# Teen show from the 80s where a teen talked to a girl in the future on his computer

Tags: story-identification, tv

There used to be this teen show I watched every Saturday morning in the 80s with this guy who spoke to a girl on his computer from the future. I think the boy's mom was either divorced or his father deceased. I can't remember which. Anyone remember this sci fi show?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand one sentence. Was (a) the boy's computer from the future, and he used the computer to talk to a girl; or (b) the boy's computer was from the same time as the boy, and he used the computer to talk to a girl, the girl being in the future? Was this live action or animation? It's not "Out of this World" for sure, that had a girl using a 'cube' to talk to her absent father who is an extraterrestrial on another planet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Was this live-action or animated?  Was it a half-hour show or a full hour?  What did they talk about?  What drove the plot?

Comment: Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starstuff) that Starstuff (see both answers currently below) aired only in the Philadelphia market.  Was that where you were in the 80's?

Comment: I was in Philadelphia at the time. It was a local program I found out once I looked up the name. Star stuff was the name of the show.

Answer (score 12):

Searching some keywords, I think this is likely the TV show [Starstuff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starstuff) which originally ran for one season in 1980 and later ran in repeats, the [imdb summary](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0415451/plotsummary/?ref_=tt_ov_pl) says:

> An early '80s Saturday morning live-action T.V. show. Chris, a ten-year-old boy, while playing with his home-made computer in his bedroom, accidentally taps into a computer belonging to Ingrid, a ten-year-old girl who lives on a space station thirty years in the future. They would frequently share Laurel and Hardy episodes, kid-made news clips and a puppet short called "The Edge of Space", starring Krikles, Zornad and their robot Giz.

There are a few episodes on [this youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/@starstuff6951/videos), here's episode 7:

Comment: Thank you. That was the exact show I was thinking of. I couldn't remember the name for the life of me.

Answer (score 5):

That is most likely *Starstuff* (1980).

Here is a summary from IMDB: "An early '80s Saturday morning live-action T.V. show. Chris, a ten-year-old boy, while playing with his home-made computer in his bedroom, accidentally taps into a computer belonging to Ingrid, a ten-year-old girl who lives on a space station thirty years in the future. They would frequently share Laurel and Hardy episodes, kid-made news clips and a puppet short called "The Edge of Space", starring Krikles, Zornad and their robot Giz."

[IMDB link](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0415451/)

Comment: Thank you. That was the exact show I was thinking of. I couldn't remember the name for the life of me.